# What sites offer installing Ubuntu packages with apturl

Tags: 11.10, websites, apturl

Are there any sites that offer installing ubuntu packages through apturl. The only one I know for now is http://appnr.com/ but what others exists with a similar way of installing packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use http://apps.ubuntu.com

For exmaple, To install VLC from this site you can link like this:

http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc

Instead of the normal apt-url:

apt://vlc

which doesn't work on ask-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

There is **apt.ubuntu.com**

For exmaple, To install `VLC` from this site you can link like this:

[**http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc)